# Tokenizing a multi-language text field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following table which contains millions of documents data in the form of a json file:

```
 +-------+---------------------------------------+------------+
 | doc_id|           doc_text                    | doc_lang   |
 +-------+---------------------------------------+------------+
 |  doc1 | "first /resource X 'title' "          |    en      |
 |  doc2 | "<r>ressource 2 @titre en France"     |    Fr      |
 |  doc3 | "die Tür geöffnet?"                   |    ge      |
 |  doc4 | "$risorsa 4 <in> lingua italiana"     |    It      |
 |  ...  | " ........."                          |    ..      |
 |  ...  | "........."                           |    ..      |
 +-------+---------------------------------------+------------+
```

I need to do the following:

1. Tokenizing, filtering and stopwords removing for each document text using an appropriate analyzer (dynamically) according to the text language shown in doc_lang field (let's say European languages).
2. Getting TF and IDF for each term inside doc_text field.(no search operations are required, just for scoring)

Q) Could anybody advice me if Elasticsearch is a good choice in this case?

P.S. I am looking for something compatible with Apache Spark.

Comment: @kimchy , please I need your help, if you have time!

Answer (score 0):

Include language code in the doc_text field when indexing like

```
{ "doc_id": "doc", "doc_text_en": "xxx", "doc_lang": "en"}
```

Then you will be able to specify dynamic mapping of lang-specific analyzer.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: do you mean I should create a new column for each language?

Comment: there's no columns in ES, every document may have different set of fields, it's normal way to use ES